# How to make a django field read only for a non staff user in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here is my django model;

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="books")
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.book.title}"
```

Here is the serializer;

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book = BookSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        exclude = ["user"]
```

here is the viewset;

```
class OrderItemAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = OrderItemSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, pk, shipping_address_pk):
        book = generics.get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
        order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
            user=request.user, book=book, ordered=False
        )
        shipping_address = generics.get_object_or_404(
            ShippingAddress, pk=shipping_address_pk
        )
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user, shipping_address=shipping_address
        )
        
        order.items.add(order_item)
        book.stock -= 1
        book.save()
        order.save()

        serializer_context = {"request": request}
        serializer = self.serializer_class(order_item, context=serializer_context)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

How do I prevent non staff users from changing the **ordered** field or making the field read-only for non staff users

Comment: you can override method in `ViewSet` for change `Serializer`. Can you share code in `ViewSet` which `OrderItemSerializer` used?

Comment: Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41370106/1079086

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good answer based on different serializers depends on user role and *get_serializer_class* method in your view.

[Django REST API: Make field read-only for certain permission level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366832/django-rest-api-make-field-read-only-for-certain-permission-level)