# How to disallow to change "status" for simple user and keep it for admin and support(superuser)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

The simple user must either not see the status button or it must be grayed out for selection. Admin(user.is_staff) and Support(user.is_superuser) should see the field and be able to change it.

Now user can change the status of ticket in Update view.

[image]

My serializer:

```
class TicketSerializerUpdate(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    status = Status.objects.all()

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = "__all__"
```

My models Ticket and Status:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    desc_status = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status


class Ticket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    text = models.TextField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

File permissions now haven't anything for solve the problem and I haven't any idea. I think it is simple problem, if you need more info you can request me)

Comment: answered here, maybe helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/41370106/16004568

Comment: @Amrez, thanks for information, I also checked http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different Serializers for different users in your view using `get_serializer_class()`:

```
class SimpleUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields =  ('status',)

class AdminUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = "__all__"

class ExampleView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):    
    ...
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_admin:
            return AdminUserSerializer
        return SimpleUserSerializer
```

Comment: I do it's and get this error:
TypeError at /api/tickets/
View.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: In view

`class TicketAPIList(TicketAPIBase, ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    serializer_class = ExampleView
    ...`

Comment: ExampleView is a view class not a Serializer class. You did not include the View class originally so I didn't know how to name it. `ExampleView` is your TicketAPIList basically so just use that method override of `get_serializer_class` in your `TicketAPIList`